# custom JAVA SDK file in android studio project

Tags: java, sdk

Client provide me a SDK file to build a RFID Reader Apps for Handheld Device.
How to use or open custom JAVA SDK file in my Android Studio IDE.

I tried to open that file in my Android Studio IDE but I failed because There was no gradle file.
Please give me suggestion ,how I open SDK.

Comment: What kind / type of file is the SDK?  ("SDK" is not a file type ...)

Comment: Please read [ask] and write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title.